# "UnityException: Android NDK not found" On Jenkins Compile

Tags: unity-game-engine, jenkins, android-ndk

The Log said:

```
Android PostProcess task "Detecting Android SDK" took 3004.9653 ms
DisplayProgressbar: Detect Android NDK
UnityException: Android NDK not found
Android NDK not found or invalid. Please, fix it in Edit / Unity -> Preferences -> External Tools
```

On the Unity, everything work fine. The Script working well. NDK is working fine. I check the NDK Version and the Environment, everything is correct. I already try to add environment on the jenkins and change the NDK to the default version install by unity hub. But the problem is still not solved.